# Do not print NA when printing data frame

Tags: r, na, output-formatting

For `data frames` there is no `na.print` [option](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.dataframe.html). Is there any workaround to suppress display of NAs?

Sample data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
       x=c("a","b","c","d"),
       a=c(1,1,1,1),
       b=c(1,1,1,NA),
       c=c(1,1,NA,NA),
       d=c(1,NA,NA,NA))      
df
```

Results in:

```
  x a  b  c  d
1 a 1  1  1  1
2 b 1  1  1 NA
3 c 1  1 NA NA
4 d 1 NA NA NA
```

But I would like to show:

```
  x a  b  c  d
1 a 1  1  1  1
2 b 1  1  1
3 c 1  1
4 d 1
```

Comment: Warning: make sure neither you nor your readers are misled into thinking there is either "nothing at all" or "zero" (as Excel cheerfully does) in the blank locations.  If this is purely for publication, fine; otherwise be careful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace missing values by `""` (this technique is used in `print.dist` S3 method)

```
cf <- format(dat) ## use format to set other options like digits, justify , ...
cf[is.na(dat)] <- ""
 cf
  x a  b  c  d
1 a 1  1  1  1
2 b 1  1  1   
3 c 1  1      
4 d 1
```

Answer (score 6):

There is, but you have to coerce to a matrix first...

```
print( as.matrix(df) , na.print = "" , quote = FALSE )
     x a b  c  d 
[1,] a 1  1  1  1
[2,] b 1  1  1   
[3,] c 1  1      
[4,] d 1
```

Whip it into a little function if you like...

```
nona <- function(x){
    print( as.matrix(x) , na.print = "" , quote = FALSE )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `write.table`:

```
write.table(dfr,sep="\t",col.names=NA,na="")
""      "x"     "a"     "b"     "c"     "d"
"1"     "a"     1       1       1       1
"2"     "b"     1       1       1       
"3"     "c"     1       1               
"4"     "d"     1
```